# How to modify the url in the search results?

Tags: display-template

I am using sp 2013 on prem. I created a new page and used the search result pagelayout. On this page you have the OOTB refiner, search box, search resultscript webparts. I would like to clone some display template and modify the url in the search results. I would like to add some dynamic querystring like ?bla=123. How can I do this?

[image]